# Django template context not working with date template tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm passing the date as an entire string as below:

```
def template_test(request):

    context = {
        'day': '2021-04-19T03:00:00Z',
    }

    return render(request, 'date_test.html', context=context)
```

date_test.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<p>Here is the day {{ day|date:"l, j M y" }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone know why when I add a date template tag on my day variable it doesn't work? If I remove it, the day variable is showing normally but with filter not.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ;
return render(request, 'date_test.html', context)

Answer (score 0):

The string you provide does not match Django's `date` filter requirements. According to its [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

> The format passed can be one of the predefined ones [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT),
> [DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT), [SHORT_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SHORT_DATE_FORMAT) or [SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT), or a custom format that uses the format specifiers shown in the table above. Note that predefined formats may vary depending on the current locale.

---

To fix this, you can use `parse_datetime` from `django.utils.dateparse` as follows:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

def template_test(request):
    context = {
        'day': parse_datetime('2021-04-19T03:00:00Z')
    }

    return render(request, 'date_test.html', context=context)
```